# Monologue Blogging Engine Ruby on Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, monologue

I am attempting to deploy the Monologue blogging engine on Ruby on Rails. I cannot figure out why the output is not HTML formatted. Also, I can save new posts, but cannot save them as published. I have deployed Monologue before, but not on Rails 4.0. The site is viewable here:

http://agile-cliffs-3521.herokuapp.com/blogg/monologue# .

I am left in the dark, as there are no errors or output to push me in the right direction. I have pulled the correct gem, and have found all compatible dependencies.

Comment: Can you post your heroku logs?

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Monologue is not yet working for Rails 4. There is a PR to add that support on master soon-ish: https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue/pull/162.

Feel free to [crreate an issue](https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue/issues/new) for anything not working as you wish and/or post on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/monologue-rb).

Best.